# Generic Stack not "pushing" necessary elements

Tags: java, file, stack, java.util.scanner

I am currently in the process of debugging some code that I have for a problem that is supposed to check to see if there is a balance of opening and closing brackets. For this I am using the generic stack that I made to contain al the brackets. This is my main code

```
/* Following the specification in the README.md file, provide your 
 * SymbolBalance class.
 * test these: { }’s, ( )'s, [ ]'s, " "’s, and /* * /’s are properly balanced
 */ 

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SymbolBalance{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         if(args.length > 0){
             try{
                 Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                 MyStack<Character> balance = new MyStack<>(); 
                 String string;
                 char character; 
                 char charNext;
                 int line = 0; 
                 boolean beginning = true; 
                 // the easiest way to understand/code this problem is by
                 // reading over each individual string, then each 
                 // individual character of that string
                 while(file.hasNextLine()){
                     line++;
                     string = file.next();
                     for(int i = 0; i < string.length() - 1; i++){
                         character = string.charAt(i);
                         charNext = string.charAt(i + 1);
                         if(character == '[' || character == '{' ||
                            character == '(' || character == '/' && 
                            charNext == '*' || character == '/' && 
                            charNext == '*'){
                            balance.push(character);
                         }
                         else if(character == '*' && charNext == '/'){
                            if(balance.isEmpty()){
                            System.out.println("<"+i+">: Empty");
                            }
                            else if(balance.pop() != '*'){
                                System.out.println("<"+i+">: <"+character+">, <"+balance.pop()+">");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(character == ']'){
                            if(balance.isEmpty()){
                                System.out.println("<"+i+">: Empty");
                            }
                            else if(balance.pop() != '['){
                                 System.out.println("<"+i+">: <"+character+">, <"+balance.pop()+">");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(character == '}'){
                            if(balance.isEmpty()){
                                 System.out.println("<"+i+">: Empty");
                             }
                             else if(balance.pop() != '{'){
                                 System.out.println("<"+i+">: <"+character+">, <"+balance.pop()+">");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(character == ')'){
                            if(balance.isEmpty()){
                                System.out.println("<"+i+">: Empty");
                            }
                            else if(balance.pop() != '('){
                                 System.out.println("<"+i+">: <"+character+">, <"+balance.pop()+">");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(character == '"'){
                            if(beginning == true){
                               balance.push(character);
                            }
                            else{
                                if(balance.isEmpty()){
                                    System.out.println("<"+i+">: Empty");
                                }
                                else if(balance.pop() != '('){
                                     System.out.println("<"+i+">: <"+character+">, <"+balance.pop()+">");
                                }
                                beginning = true; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                file.close(); 
             }
             catch(FileNotFoundException e){
             System.out.println("No such file exists or cannot be found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that once my code runs, there is an error where it says that my stack is empty (from my generic stack class). This leads me to think that my characters are not being pushed into the stack (hence the empty stack exception). I have looked over my generic stack code and I am fairly confident the issue is not in that file. Is there something wrong with my if statements or is this an issue of me not using scanner correctly and as such the file itself isn't being read correctly? As a side not I have seen the file that is supposed to be read and I know it is not empty so that also is not the issue.

I am aware this will probably be a silly mistake, but I cannot seem to distinguish it right now. I would appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Comment: your call `while(file.hasNextLine()){` but then you only take `next` not `nextLine`

Comment: @ScaryWombat is there a way that I can call hasNextLine() and then move into the individual strings of that line? Thank you so much for taking the time to look over my code!

Comment: read the whole and then `split` on white char